# Show div of unknown size above another div

Tags: css

I'm trying to place the dropdown menu as the footer. When the menu receives hover event, it should place the item container on top of itself, but since the size of item container can be dynamic, it needs to be placed correctly.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="div1" class="div1">ITEM CONTAINER</div>
       <div id="div2" class="div2">MENU</div>
   </div>
```

This is the closet I got: https://jsfiddle.net/Y4kga/61/

but the problem is when I change the height of div1, the menu goes down too. I need the menu to stay in the location specified by me (margin-top: 100px). Any suggestions how can I accomplish this without jquery? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something similar to this in here:

http://codepen.io/petethewizard/pen/ByqYQM

Code for it is as follows, html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="above">
      Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
      Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
  </div>

  <div id="below"></div>
</div>
```

SASS/CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;

  #above {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 300px;
      background:skyblue;
  }

  #below {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background:green;
  }
}
```

You can set the height of the #above element to anything or just leave it to auto.